# 'Cannot call method "getRange" of null (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup the code pictured below to clear a set of cells every night around midnight in my Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I know how to set it up to run by itself. But I can't get it to run in the first place. I receive the error message seen in the first photo below; the second photo is of the debug menu.

Any suggestions for how to get this to work?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TndKa.png)

[Debug menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSX8s.png)

Answer (score -1):

Change .getActive() to .getActiveSpreadsheet()